# Need some help on extracting particular string using string manipulations with/without regex

Tags: python, string, ascii

I have an OCR program (not so accurate though) that outputs a string. I append it to a list. So, my `ss` list looks like this:

```
ss = [
     '성  벼 | 5  번YAO LIAO거 CHINA P R체류자격 결혼이민F-1)말급일자',                # 'YAO LIAO'
     '성 별 F 등록번호명 JAO HALJUNGCHINA P R격 결혼이민(F-6)밥급인자',                # 'JAO HALJUNG'
     '성   별 F명 CHENG HAIJING국 가 CHINA P R 역체 가차격   결혼이민(C-4) 박급인자',  # 'CHENG HAIJING'
     'KOa MDOVUD TAREEQ SAID HAFIZULLAH TURKIYE움첫;자격 거주(F-2)발급일자',          # 'DOVUD TAREEQ SAID HAFIZULLAH'
     'KOn 별 MDOVUD TAREEQ SAID- IIAFIZULLAH 감 TURKIYE동체나자격 거주F-2) 발급일자',  # 'DOVUD TAREEQ SAID- IIAFIZULLAH' 
     '등록번호IN" 성 별 M명 TAREEQ SAD IIAFIZULLAH 값 TURKIYE8체주자격 거주-2)발급일자' # 'TAREEQ SAD IIAFIZULLAH'
    ]
```

I need to find some way to at least remove country names, or even better solution would be to extract clean full names as shown as comments above.

Here, the `ss` list stores the worst outputs, so if I can handle all 6 strings here with one universal solution, I hope the rest will be easier.

So far, I could think of looping through each element to extract upper English-only letters and filter out empty strings and any string whose `len` is less than 2, because I am assuming name consists of at least 2 letters:

```
for s in ss:
    eng_parts = ''.join([i if 64 < ord(i) < 91 else ' ' for i in s])
    #print("English-only strings: {}".format(eng_parts))
    new_string = ''
    spaced_string_list = eng_parts.split(" ")
    for spaced_string in spaced_string_list:
        if len(spaced_string) >= 2:
            new_string += spaced_string + " "
    new_string_list.append(new_string)
```

where `new_string_list` is `['YAO LIAO CHINA ', 'JAO HALJUNGCHINA ', 'CHENG HAIJING CHINA ', 'KO MDOVUD TAREEQ SAID HAFIZULLAH TURKIYE ', 'KO MDOVUD TAREEQ SAID IIAFIZULLAH TURKIYE ', 'IN TAREEQ SAD IIAFIZULLAH TURKIYE ']`

Could this result be improved further?

**EDIT:**
The desired name string could be of up to 5 space-separated substrings. Also, a part of the name string is at least two English-only upper letters. In some cases, a name substring could be separated by a `-` (refer to `SAID-` case) if it reaches the end of the ID card, where initially the whole string got extracted from.

Comment: What are the requirements? I'd think of each line's first match consisting of at least two words composed from at least two `[A-Z]`. This would result in: [`^.*?([A-Z]{2,}(?: [A-Z]{2,})+)`](https://regex101.com/r/LR5QT8/1) where the desired part gets [captured](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) to the *first group*. Or limit it to maximum of three words [like this demo](https://regex101.com/r/FY17tc/1).

Comment: It can be further restricted by [lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to spare out certain substrings [like this demo](https://regex101.com/r/1nDfEG/1).

Comment: @bobblebubble, I edited the question, please take a look.

Comment: Regarding your edit maybe something like [`^.*?([A-Z]{2,}(?: [A-Z-]+){1,5})`](https://regex101.com/r/Nj2o6z/1)

Comment: [this is better](https://regex101.com/r/1nDfEG/1), but still doesn't generalize to other strings. Do I have to exclude all country names by hard-coding?

Comment: How would you distinguish the country part when not excluding them manually?

Comment: I mean the way you did is good, I assume there is no other way around it, right?

Comment: I could not see anything to distinguish the country from name myself.

Answer (score 1):

It is a great idea to postulate that a name always is build of two upper-case words of Latin characters separated by a space (or more).

So you can loop through the elements and look for that pattern. *regex* is the library to use =):

```py
import re

for el in ss:
    m = re.search(r'[A-Z]{2,}(\s+[A-Z\-]{2,})+', el)
    if m:
        print(m.group())
```

> YAO LIAO
> JAO HALJUNGCHINA
> CHENG HAIJING
> MDOVUD TAREEQ SAID HAFIZULLAH TURKIYE
> MDOVUD TAREEQ SAID- IIAFIZULLAH
> TAREEQ SAD IIAFIZULLAH

Let's examine the pattern in detail:

- `[A-Z]{2,}` this searches for upper-case Latin characters of length 2 or more. The brackets indicate a symbol range and the curly brackets a numeric range.
- `\s+` looks for one ore more (`+`) widespaces (`\s`)
- add special characters to the list of allowed character if necessary. Note that e.g. a dash needs to be escaped `\-` because it signifies a range otherwise `-`
- group fractions of the pattern to make it repeatable: `( )+`

Comment: great, but it doesn't fulfill my task, I need a whole name up until a country name appears. So, for example: `'DOVUD TAREEQ SAID- IIAFIZULLAH'` should be extracted. Name could be up to five 5 words, each word containing at least two letters.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to include the dash as a special character in the second pattern. And I repeated the second fraction so that names can consist out of arbitrary many components (but at least two)